# Why are there extra bits set in my EFI variable attributes, and how can I modify the values while preserving these attributes?

Tags: linux, uefi, apple

I'm running Linux 5.10-rc2 on a MacBook Pro from 2015.  I'm trying to modify EFI variables to better understand how they work.  However, when I try to modify them with `efivar`, I get an `Invalid argument` error.  Using `strace` shows the following:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/SPIKeyboardNoComm-4d1ede05-38c7-4a6a-9cc6-4bcca8b38c14", O_WRONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=8, ...}) = 0
write(4, "\7\0\0\200\22\0\0\0", 8)      = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

Referencing `fs/efivarfs/file.c` in Linux, the only way `-EINVAL` is returned from a write is if the length of data written is less than the four bytes required for attributes, or if the attributes specify bits not in `EFI_VARIABLE_MASK`.  It looks like the latter here.  Referencing `include/linux/efi.h`, the first three bits indicate non-volatile, boot access, and runtime access, but the highest order bit, which is not in the mask, is also set.

I wrote a small script to print the attribute bits for all of the EFI variables on this machine, and they all have the highest bit set.  What does this mean?  Is there any way to unset it, so that tools like efivar work?  Clearly there is a bug somewhere; is it with the `efivar` tool, the Linux kernel, or the EFI implementation on this machine?

Also, this problem was not always here.  I was able to set the variable in the example above (an Apple-specific one related to the keyboard) before a reboot.  I didn't check what the attributes were before I encountered this problem.